# Backbone problem with this object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my View in Backbone framework:

```
jQuery(document)ready(function() { 

com.company.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function() {
     myCollection.bind('add', this.onSuccess);
  },

  onSuccess : function(model) {
    // do something
    this.somethingElse();
  },

  somethingElse : function() {
    // do something else
  }
});

});
```

Now the problem is inside `onSuccess` function the this object doesn't belong to the View anymore, it belongs to model. So, when I call `this.somethingElse()` I got `undefined`.

How can I successfully call `this.somethingElse` inside `onSuccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind your function to the context of the View object.

In `initialize`, do this:

```
initialize : function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "onSuccess");
    myCollection.bind('add', this.onSuccess);
}
```

Comment: I got this error when I run my code against Jasmine. TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Comment: note.  I edited my response to be `_.bindAll`.  I screwed up with my first try.

Comment: Note that you can add as many functions as you need inside this function... like `_.bindAll(this, "onSuccess", "somethingElse");`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're relying on `this` to point to the original object.  Unlike many languages `this` in Javascript changes based on the manner in which a method is called.  Often in a callback it's invoked with `this` pointing to a different object or simply none at all (`undefined`).

One way to work around this is to remove the reliance on `this` in favor of a function local variable which can't be interferred with.  For example

```
com.company.View = Backbone.View.extend(
   return function() {
      var self = {}
      self.initialize = function() {
        myCollection.bind('add', self.onSuccess);
      };
      self.onSuccess = function(model) {
        // do something
        self.somethingElse();
      };
      self.somethingElse = function() {
        // do something else
      };
      return self;
    }();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there other ways to do that? I'm just curious.

Comment: @toy there are a few ways. Most though involve saving off the reference to the object containing `somethingElse` somewhere. The style I showed here though is a fairly common pattern for solving the problem though.

Comment: Yes.  There is a better way:  Call _.bindAll(this, "methodName") from your `initialize` function.  See my example.